# Remember URL in PHP session once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

So, I've been trying to get this to work for a while now. And I can't get it to work like I would.

What I'm trying to do is:
I have a search and filter page (where users select from checkboxes to sort products). Now when a user is finished filtering the URL has a set of specific values.

```
https://mydomein.nl/subsdir/?_sft_brand=nike&_sft_type=sneaker
```

If a user clicks on a product it will show the product page. On that page there is a button that say's `Back to overview`. Currently it links to `/subdir/` but this removes the set of values (of course).

I would like to store the link like this `https://mydomein.nl/subsdir/?_sft_brand=nike&_sft_type=sneaker` in a session so the user doesn't have to filter again.

I have tried to store the `REQUEST_URI` in a session using this code:

```
$page = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$_SESSION['page'] = $page;
echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SESSION['page'];
```

But that updates the URL every time you click on a new link. I have tried many variations of this, but all overwrite the first `REQUETS_URI`. I would like to store just the filter URL and not the URL's the user clicks on next. So I can make the `back to overview` link like `<a href="<?php echo $page; ?>">`. And have it alway's link back to the correct filters and such.

Any great idea's? Thanks for the time to read and help!

Comment: Check if isset session, if it isn't then set the value else ignore. - Essentially what you want in pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution what you should do is when user clicks to back to overview button you should refer to a function that was called when you hit search button with the respective parameters or filters and you can check session inside search

Steps to do

- first use post method instead of get when searching.
- in your search function first of all check if your $_POST is empty
- if your $_POST is not empty set your post values in session and search with the post values.
- if your post is empty then check if your session is empty or not. if your session is not empty then search with your session values and return the result.
- if your session is empty then search it with no values (i mean retrieve all products and show it)
- now when user clicks processed to overview then redirect to the search function.

Comment: I get what your saying. Except I don't know where to begin ... alas... Kind of new to this whole php thing...

Comment: if you post your search function. search form, i could do some changes

Comment: I'mma gonna do some more digging around. Thanks for the steps, It will help allot.